# PHP's Composer never works on my Windows machine

Tags: php, composer-php

For some reason, for the past few months Composer has quit working for me on my Windows PC.  Every single time I use it I get errors, always different errors but none the less, it never works.

Below is my latest error when trying to use Composer to install some packages...

```
Problem 1
    - oro/platform 1.0.0-alpha2 requires ass/xmlsecurity dev-master -> satisfiable by ass/xmlsecurity[dev-master].
    - oro/platform 1.0.x-dev requires ass/xmlsecurity dev-master -> satisfiable
by ass/xmlsecurity[dev-master].
    - ass/xmlsecurity dev-master requires lib-openssl >=0.9.0 -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for oro/platform 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by oro/platform[1.0.0-alpha2, 1.0.x-dev].
```

Does anyone know why I might be having so many problems?  I have tried re-installing Composer several times but it never fixes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dependency issue - perhaps you have removed or corrupted a package.

I know this sounds cliched, but have you tried reinstalling Composer?

Comment: Yeah I mentioned I have reinstalled composer several times over the past month with no luck.  This particular error is mentioning lib-openssl which I also made sure was installed on my machine.  There must be something strange going on.  Unfortunately many open source applications are only install-able now days with Composer so this is a huge problem

Comment: have you tried updating composer via php `php composer.phar self-update`?

Comment: another option would be to disable the openssl module in apache and remove the openssl from `php.ini`, install your packages, and then enable the module again.

Comment: or perhaps install the opensll binary as a replacement? [link](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is that if you're using WAMP you have to enable lib-openssl (and maybe some other stuff, too) in two different php.ini files, one for Apache and one for CLI.

- Apache php.ini location: *:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.*.*\bin
- CLI php.ini location: *:\wamp\bin\php\php5.*.*

Since Composer uses the command line / CLI version of PHP, that should be your first stop.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but an answer nonetheless: Do not waste your time installing OpenSSL binaries on your Windows machine.  It doesn't work and apparently has nothing to do with the problem.  (Tried both x86 and x64.)